# what is the probability?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The probability distribution of X, the duration of a phone call is given below.

X (duration of phone in minutes) : Probability

1: 0.05
2: 0.15
3: 0.20
4: 0.35
5: 0.20
6: 0.05

a) Find the probability that the duration of a phone is at least three minutes.

b) Find the Probability that the duration of the phone call is not more than 4 minutes.

c) Find average Phone call duration.

d) If the charges of a phone call are at the rate of $0.50 per minute) Express cost per call (Y ) in terms of X.

f) Obtain the average cost per call . If on an average 1000 calls are made per day obtain the revenue earned at the end of the day.

Comment: I hope all those verbs are not imperative forms. You should try to do something on your own and show it, instead of copy-pasting some exercises.

Answer (score 1):

a) P(X>=3) = P(3) + P(4) + P(5) + P(6)

b) P(X<=4) = P(1) + P(2) + P(3) + P(4)

c) 1 P(1) + 2 P(2) + 3 P(3) + 4 P(4) + 5 P(5) + 6 P(6) (weighed average with probabilities as weights...)

d) Y=X*0.5

f) Answer c) times 0.5